# I am trying to use JFileChooser to view and display a file, unable to figure out how to display file

Tags: java

I am trying to open and view a file using JFileChooser, but am having issues viewing the file. Any help or critique is open, thanks mates.

```
package jmenu_bar;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;


/**
 *
 * @author Stafford J Villavicencio
 */

public class Jmenu_Bar extends JFrame
{   

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        //create JFrame
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle(" JMenuBar Practice ");
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //create JMenuBar
        JMenuBar jbar = new JMenuBar();
        jbar.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
        //add JMenuBar to JFrame
        frame.setJMenuBar(jbar);

        //create JMenu File
        JMenu file = new JMenu(" File");
        //add seperator between sub-Options
        file.addSeparator();
        //add JMenu file to JMenuBAr
        jbar.add(file);

        //create JMenuItem exit 
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem(" Exit");
        //create ActionListener for exit
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {   
               System.exit(0);
           } 
        });
        //add exit to file menu
        file.add(exit);

        /*IM trying to have JMenuItem "open" actualy open and display selected file within the JFrame......>
        *create JMenuItem open
        */
        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem(" Open");
        //create actionListener for open
        open.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            JFileChooser fChoose = new JFileChooser();

            @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                fChoose.showOpenDialog(frame);

            }
        });
        file.add(open);

            //create JMenu edit
            JMenu edit = new JMenu(" Edit");
            jbar.add(edit);

            //create JMenuItem save
            JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem(" Save");
            edit.add(save);


    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you're having trouble "viewing" the file that the user has selected when they click "open"?

Comment: Yes my friend, that is exactly right!. I am able to choose the file but unable to view it once chosen. If you see towards the bottom of the program I am using JMenuItem "open" to do as the item suggests but I am having issues with the logic.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Comment: Yes I have thanks to all of the input, from my stackoverflow brethren.

Comment: Glad to hear it :) I see that you're new here, so just a heads up: If my answer (or anyone else's) was useful to you, please feel free to accept it by clicking the arrow beside it. Doing so will give you +2 reputation points and also increase the likelihood that folks will help you out in the future. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

All the file choose does is give you the name of a file to read. You are still responsible for reading the text of the file and loading it into a Swing component.

I would suggest using a JTextArea to display a text file. Then you can just use the read(...) method.

First you should read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use A File Chooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). Then once you get the file name you can do something like:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader( the file name );
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( reader );
textArea.read(br, null);
```

Code is untested, I'll let you work out the details.

Comment: Again I have come to the right place, I love coding and aspire to become SR level. Thanks mate, have a virtual beer on me.

Answer (score 0):

i looked at your program, it shows nothing to me...you just messed up, lets take a look at my code of JFile Chooser.. this code is just an example, this code opens the .gif, .jpg file, means it works as a image viewer,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class ImageViewer extends JFrame 
{
    static JFileChooser imageChooser = new JFileChooser();
    static JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();


  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
    //construct frame
    new ImageViewer().show();
  }
  public ImageViewer() 
  {
    // create frame
    setTitle("Image Viewer");
    setResizable(false);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
    {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
      {
        exitForm(e);
      }
    });
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


    GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    String[] ext = new String[] {"gif", "jpg"};

    gridConstraints.gridy = 0;
    getContentPane().add(imageChooser, gridConstraints);
    imageChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
      {
        imageChooserActionPerformed(e);
      }
    });
        imageLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270, 300));
        imageLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));    imageLabel.setOpaque(true);
        imageLabel.setBackground(Color.white);
        imageLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        imageLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        getContentPane().add(imageLabel, gridConstraints);

        pack();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((int) (0.5 * (screenSize.width - getWidth())), (int) (0.5 * (screenSize.height - getHeight())), getWidth(), getHeight());


  }
  private void imageChooserActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  {
    // create and display graphic if open selected
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION))
    {
      ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon(imageChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
      imageLabel.setIcon(myImage);
    }
  }


  private void exitForm(WindowEvent e)
  {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! I am still learning so much as a software engineer, I love how when I am able to see a more senior level programmers work it motivates me just that much more. Shukriya.

Comment: no Im just a very unusual American.... I love the Indian culture and wanted to show respect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying that you don't know how to see which file the user has selected.

```
        final JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();

        int returnVal = jfc.showOpenDialog(this);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
           File selected = jfc.getSelectedFile();
           //do something with the file

    } 
}
```

use `int returnVal = jfc.showOpenDialog(this);` to launch the open dialog. This way, when the user clicks a button (either cancel or approve(open)), it will return an int value. So, the if statement says: If the button clicked was "open", then get the file they chose, call it selected and do something with it.

Let me know if I need to walk you through anything in more depth.